# Find me and learn the truth!

Tags: cipher, rhyme, steganography, letters

Figure out the jumble and set me free.

Encrypt the below text and find me!

> C W   G   N   W   B   V   W   L   N   V   I   B   G   O   Q   R   U   I   Q

Before you fall into the trap,

I can help you with the below map.

Update-

Map is a map. Not an answer. Its a path towards the solution.

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

**Update#**

Clue 1 -

> The solution will have 3 steps. Key to decryption starts with 4.

Clue 2 -

> The characters do not have any spaces.

Clue 3 -

> This is how the answer will look X XX XXXXX XX XXXXX XX XXX

Clue 4 -

> Where am I? My origin is NULL,NULL. I may not be straight forward.

Comment: I've been trying anything on this. The map was fairly easy to figure out but the letters... O_O

Comment: Yeah. Hints should be easier I guess else there no use of a puzzle. :)

Comment: @Techidiot: Well, the message reads that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So here it goes -

**I may not be straight forward.**

> Reverse the characters
>  
>
>     **Characters** => Q    I   U  R   Q   O   G   B   I   V   N   L   W   V   B   W   N   G   W  C
>
>      **Positions(Original Position MOD 26)** => 17     9   21 0   17  15  16  2   17  22  14  0   23  22  2   23  14  7   23  3

**Key to decryption starts with 4.**

> 4 = FOUR = F+O+U+R = 6+15+21+18=**60**
>
>
>  **Formula** 
>  
>  (Letter - 60) MOD 26
>
>  e.g. **(17-60) MOD 26 = 9**
>
>    Gives us the following numbers - 
>
>
> **Positions**=>9  1   13  18  9   7   8   20  9   14  6   18  15  14  20  15  6   25  15  21
>
>
>  **Characters**=>I   A   M   R   I   G   H   T   I   N   F   R   O   N   T   O   F   Y   O   U

So the answer is ->

> **I AM RIGHT IN FRONT OF YOU**

The encryption steps - >

> Letters - I A M R I G H T I N F R O N T O F Y O U
>
>  Position(Position + 60) - 69 61  73  78  69  67  68  80  69  74  66  78  75  74  80  75  66  85  75  81
>  
>
>  New Position(Old Position MOD 26) - 17   9   21  0   17  15  16  2   17  22  14  0   23  22  2   23  14  7   23  3
>
>   Characters - Q  I   U   R   Q   O   G   B   I   V   N   L   W   V   B   W   N   G   W   C
>  
>
>  Reverse- C   W   G   N   W   B   V   W   L   N   V   I   B   G   O   Q   R   U   I   Q

Comment: I feel that the formula seems a bit to complex - there should be some more clues on what it should look like

Comment: Have you retrofitted the original list of number? For example, why is I 17 in one place? Why is the first G 16? And why are R and L 0, which are not valid letter indices in your representation? The solution looks good, but it is just rot18.

Comment: Oh, wait! You are answering your own question here. If that's the official explanation, it is not convincing. You have transformation errors when you calculate the letter positions. You also don't explain how the puzzle is supposed to be solved. All explanations are based on additional hints, not on the puzzle itself.

Comment: I thought it was not an interesting question as I didn't got enough questions/doubts from guys hence decided to add an answer. And yes, I have updated the answer. Hope that clarifies. Not sure if my hints helped or may be people didn't bothered much.

Comment: The puzzle, as written, when reversed and ROT18'd, reads "I AM JIGYT AN FDONT OF YOU", which, when non-reversed, is easy to mistake for gibberish. Slightly modified spelling with the intent of throwing off the solver can be OK sometimes, but it usually should be accompanied by a hint telling them to expect it. Also, I don't see how 'map' and 'origin of (null,null)' helped toward finding the solution.

Answer (score 3):

First thoughts:

> The 'map' should be arranged so the pieces fit together like this:
>
> [image][image][image][image]
> [image][image][image][image]
> [image][image][image][image]
> [image][image][image][image]

Which is clearly

> An upside-down 4

Comment: Good. You are on your path towards solution. But its definitely not an answer. :) Should have been a comment. Hence downvoting.

Comment: @Techidiot, ever heard of [partial answers?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/handling-puzzles-with-multiple-steps-and-the-posting-of-partial-answers) these are acceptable, and a downvote is ridiculous

Comment: @Techidiot, observe some other puzzles and go through the help center, will help massively in the future

Comment: Sure thing! Will take care of that. All the best to you on this one. You are on your way :)

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, I got stuck. :P

I did a thing fundamentally wrong (counting is hard) and as such, my musings are incorrect. They are left below until I get a chance to revisit the puzzle.

> Noting that the <del>length of the ciphertext equals the number of images</del>, and that the images can be re-arranged to create an upside-down '4' (see Beastly Gerbil's answer for an image), we can arrange the ciphertext with the same pattern (a period is in the spaces where the image is completely white):
>
> ```
> .W..
> OQCW
> .NWB
> .UI.
> ```
>
> Applying ROT4 (the image is a rotated '4'):
>
> ```
> .A..
> SUGA
> .RAF
> .YM.
> ```
>
> This looks like plausible plaintext, so now we need to figure out where the all-white tiles go. Assuming that they are already in the correct order as much as possible gives us this ciphertext:
>
> ```
> VWLN
> OQCW
> GNWB
> RUIQ
> ```
>
> And this plaintext:
>
> ```
> ZAPR
> SUGA
> KRAF
> VYMU
> ```
>
> Darn. Other arrangements of the all-white tiles don't seem to produce readable output either.

Comment: Should have been a comment. :)

Comment: @Phlarx don't worry about the down vote, he downvoted both of ours, obviously doesn't have enough experience on this site

Comment: Thanks. Took it away. Yes I am new. Sorry for that.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I saw your response. I was going to say the same, but you beat me to it.

Comment: All the best. You got the path right. Reach your next destination.

Comment: There are 20 characters, but only 16 images

Comment: I guess you have already used the images to find rotated 4

Comment: @Sconibulus yes, apparently I miscounted - explains why I got stuck. Musta been tired or something.